# How do I disable WebGL error mesasges/warnings in the console?

Tags: javascript, browser, webgl

This is what my debug console looks like in chome:

[image: Lots of webgl warnings]

Thing is, I'm using a WebGL framework do draw everything and I don't have the means to debug it. My app works well despite some vertices being out of range / off-screen. Can I just silence the warnings so that people who visit my website don't see them (and so that I can debug the site without this spam)?

**EDIT**

I know it's always better to fix the bug than shut up the message. However in this case I've confirmed that the problem was likely with my graphics card (specifically, the problem was fixed after I stopped a bitcoin miner that was running on my computer). Before downvoting, consider that a google search on this topic doesn't currently have very many useful results. Thanks.

Comment: `access out of range vertices` are not "*off-screen*". Either `drawElements` is provided with wrong `count` or `offset` arguments or the indexbuffer is either not bound or contains out of range indices.

Comment: @LJᛃ Ok, but that's not my question. I'll have to file a bug with the WebGL framework that I'm using, however I can't just redo all my code in a new framework at this point and I don't have time to wait for a fix. So what would you suggest? For all practical purposes, my app works exactly as expected, except for the spammy, unprofessional console messages.

Comment: **For everyone telling me to fix the bug and down-voting: I found the problem. There was a problem with my graphics card, apparently due to other software that was running on my computer. After fixing the problem the web app works fine.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to turn off the error messages. You have to just stop doing whatever it is that's generating the error

That bug means something isn't getting drawn. Since you clearly don't care if it's getting drawn or not then stop trying to draw whatever it is that causing the error message.

To find out what that is *bisect*. Remove half the things you're drawing. If you don't get the error any more then the issue is one of the half of the things you removed. If you still get the error remove the other half. Do you still get it? if that removes the error you know the issue is in the second half of stuff you removed.

Now remove the half of the half and so on. Keep doing that until you find the object(s) that are causing the error. Since they weren't being drawn anyway just remove them from your code.

Comment: Ok thanks. Unfortunately the stuff being drawn is a bunch of randomly-generated gears. All the gears are exactly the same (except for # of teeth, radius, and color), yet sometimes the random configuration generates the errors and other times it doesn't. I've noticed that it definitely happens when things are outside the bounds of the canvas (not sure why though). I'll try to debug it a bit.

Comment: Use a [pseudo random number generator](https://gist.github.com/greggman/eedf0994127d5593824f1533444606f0) so that the numbers are always the same. When bisecting always call the random number generator even if you don't actually use it for a particular gear so that you again always get the same numbers for each gear. From that you should be able to bisect and figure out which combination of random numbers is causing the issue.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this answer. It **is** factually the answer. The thing isn't being drawn, the OP is happy with it not being drawn  but they want to stop the error. The only way to stop the error is to stop drawing it. There is no option that turns off the errors. If they can't find the error by looking the easiest way is to biscet. What's the downvote for?

Comment: looks like someone just plowed through here and down-voted all the answers. I got two new upvotes on the question though. People are dumb.

Comment: I guess the answer to "Can I silence the warnings" is not "fix your code" but rather "no, you can't", so I guess the first part of the answer is kind of irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to turn it off unless you want to maybe override console.warn in your global object and suppress warnings

```
console.warn = function() {}.bind(console.warn);
console.warn('warning'); // nothing gets printed
```

Comment: Nice try, but it doesn't seem to work. WebGL probably has a backdoor to console.warn (at least on Chrome where I'm testing it).

Answer (score -1):

you could try overriding console.log/warn globally, if you don't need the console for any other reason just assign it to an empty function

```
console.log = function(){};
```

If you still need the console for other messages you could try with an if statement:

```
let newConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function(message){
    if (message !== "message that you dont want logged"){
        newConsoleLog(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion. See my response to the other David.